# Python getting Docker Container Name from the inside of a docker container

Tags: python, docker

I need to get the containers name, from within the running container in python

i could easily get the container id from inside the container in python with

```
bashCommand = """head -1 /proc/self/cgroup|cut -d/ -f3"""
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
print output
```

now i need the containername

Comment: What would you do with this information if you had it?  A process in a container has a pretty limited ability to interact with its outside world.

Comment: i need to save the containername in a mysqldb to the running script informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the Name at runtime like:

```
docker run --name MYCOOLCONTAINER alpine:latest
```

Then:

```
bashCommandName = `echo $NAME`

output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommandName]) 

print output
```

Comment: This got me on the right track (so thank you!), but for people still struggling, the syntax that worked for me was --name container_name, not NAME="CONTAINERNAME"

Comment: The container name refers to the name given to it in Docker via the `--name` parameter, not an environment variable...

Comment: Can I do this on a windows container? When i try 'hostname' on powershell, I get the container id. But get error for 'name' or $name

Comment: Try `$NAME` (case sensitive)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Docker 20.10.6 on Ubuntu 20.04:
Start the container with an interactive shell: `docker run -it --rm --name MYCOOLCONTAINER alpine:latest sh`. There, I run `set` to view all environment variables. However none contains MYCOOLCONTAINER.